# GA4 - Create Event (and Event Rule) via api

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am using GA Admin nodejs client to create an Event using this example:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/blob/main/packages/google-analytics-admin/samples/generated/v1alpha/analytics_admin_service.create_event_create_rule.js

Here is the nodejs documentation: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/analytics-admin/latest/google.analytics.admin.v1alpha.IEventCreateRule.html

Can someone please tell me what destinationEvent should be?

I am getting:

"The value for the 'destination_event' field was empty, but must be provided."

I tried both destinationEvent and destination_event with null/empty value/string but keep getting the same result.

This is how I am passing the data:

```
{
    {
    "parent": "properties/4xx5/dataStreams/6xx3",
    "eventCreateRule": {
        "name": "Click",
        "destinationEvent": "click",
        "eventConditions": [
            {
                "field": "event_name",
                "comparisonType": "EQUALS",
                "value": "click",
                "negated": false
            },
            {
                "field": "link",
                "comparisonType": "EQUALS",
                "value": "tel:",
                "negated": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I removed the unnecessary "name": "Click," but the error persisted. I retested it just now, and it seems to be working. It's possible that, being in the alpha stage, Google is making modifications.